# Display a widget if the user is an admin flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, admin

I have a "settings" screen where the user can click on "Admin mode" and then is asked for a password. If this password corresponds to a defined password that I'll give to the admins of the app, he has the app displaying all the admin widgets on the other screens.
I want to set a default admin password, when the user click on the "validate" button, the program check is the password is correct. I have a button on a screen that is like the "admin panel" and I want this button to be displayed only if the user is an admin.
Here is the Dialog I created and where I suppose I'll have to create something to check if the password is correct in the onPressed function.

```
class DialogModeAdmin extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  String _passAdmin;
  dialogContent(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black26,
            blurRadius: 10.0,
            offset: const Offset(0.0, 10.0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 120,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Text("Mot de passe"),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 1,
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(10, 10, 10, 0.25),
                    blurRadius: 5.0,
                    spreadRadius: -2.0,
                    offset: Offset(3.0, 5.0),
                  )],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                ),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0, top: 1.0, bottom: 4.0),
                    child: FormBuilderTextField(
                      // validator: FormBuilderValidators.required(context),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                      name: 'passadmin',
                      onChanged: (String value) {
                        _passAdmin = value;
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                )
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 30,
                width: 90,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Color.fromRGBO(255, 64, 0, 1.0),
                    onPrimary: Colors.white,
                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),     
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async{
                    if(_fbKey.currentState.validate()){
                      // check if the password is correct and then set a local variable to true to set the privileges of an admin
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Valider'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: dialogContent(context),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a `isAdmin` boolean in a static way or with ChangeNotifier (similar to observable).

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html

Then use this value to show/hide your widgets with the Visibility Widget

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html

```
 Visibility(
              visible: // isAdmin variable,
              child: ...
            ),
```

**EDIT :** For your problem to check the password :

```
class DialogModeAdmin extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  String _passAdmin;
  // This is your password
  final String _password = "MyPassword";

  dialogContent(BuildContext context) {
    ...
                      
                      name: 'passadmin',
                      // Here you store correctly what the user typed
                      onChanged: (String value) {
                        _passAdmin = value;
                      },
                    ),
    ...
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  ...
                  onPressed: () async{
                    if(_fbKey.currentState.validate()){
                      // check if the password is correct and then set a local variable to true to set the privileges of an admin
                      // As the comment says : 
                     if(_passAdmin == _password){
                       // set the static/valueNotifier to true
                     } else {
                       // display an error 'wrong password'
                     }
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Valider'),
                ),
         ...
}
```

Comment: Oh wow I forgot about the Visibility widget that I was using with another widget haha Thanks ! But where I’m struggling is with the password thing, I can’t manage to get the verification between a stored password in a String var and the password types by the user

Comment: You're clsoe to the solution. I edited my answer

Comment: Took me a long time to get Shared_Preferences work to use a variable between the screens but I finally managed to get it work after a few hours of struggling ! Thanks for your help !